# Angular route page successfully but not showed html content

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-ui-router

When I clicked Home in nav bar it goes to home url but not showed html content
Here is my app.routing.module.ts

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
const routes: Routes = [ 
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is my app.component.html

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link "  routerLink='home' routerLinkActive='active'>Home</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class = "container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
```

Comment: Please, can you share your console output?

Comment: Create the testing component Home2Component and modify `routes` to temporary use this one. This way you will check whether there is problem in your HomeComponent

Comment: Show the Console output , please

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line:

```
  <a class="nav-link "  routerLink='home' routerLinkActive='active'>Home</a>
```

try adding (/) before home in routerLink like this:

```
  <a class="nav-link "  routerLink='/home' routerLinkActive='active'>Home</a>
```

Comment: Since he's on the app component (root), I don't think that would be the issue.

Comment: No it is not the issue

Comment: is it rendering in the ts file of the HomeController?